# Web API action selection based on Accept header

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

Queue long introduction...

I have a resource defined at

```
http://my-awesome-product.com/api/widgets/3
```

which represents a widget with an `id` of 3. In Web API I would define a controller to serve that resource as follows:

```cs
public class WidgetsController : ApiController
{
    public Widget Get(int id)
    {
        return new Widget(...);
    }
}
```

Now, the `Widget` class could potentially be quite big, and wanting to save bandwidth from the database to the web server, and from the web server to the client, I create several DTO classes which contain a restricted number of fields of the overall `Widget`. For example:

```cs
public class WidgetSummary
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class FullWidgetForEditing
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Weight { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public decimal Width { get; set; }
    public decimal Height { get; set; }
    public decimal Depth { get; set; }
}

public class WidgetForDropDownList
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

With these `Widget` representations, the client would request the `WidgetSummary` for display on a summary grid of all the `Widget`s in the system, it would request the `FullWidgetForEditing` on the edit page of a specific `Widget`, and it would request the `WidgetForDropDownList` for use in a drop down list on the order form.

From what I understand about REST, to access a `Widget` there should be a single URL as it is a single resource, regardless of its representation and the client should specify `Accept` headers with a media type parameter to retrieve the `Widget` in its different forms, e.g. `my-awesome-product.type=widgetsummary`, `my-awesome-product.type=fullwidgetforediting`, and `my-awesome-product.type=widgetfordropdownlist`.

I could achieve that in Web API by inspecting the headers of the request like so:

```cs
public class WidgetsController : ApiController
{
    public object Get(int id)
    {
        if (Request.Headers.Accept.Any(x => x.Parameters.Any(y => y.Name == "my-awesome-product.type" && y.Value == "widgetsummary")))
        {
            return new WidgetSummary(...);
        }
        else if (Request.Headers.Accept.Any(x => x.Parameters.Any(y => y.Name == "my-awesome-product.type" && y.Value == "fullwidgetforediting")))
        {
            return new FullWidgetForEditing(...);
        }
        else if (Request.Headers.Accept.Any(x => x.Parameters.Any(y => y.Name == "my-awesome-product.type" && y.Value == "widgetfordropdownlist")))
        {
            return new WidgetForDropDownList(...);
        }

        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable);
    }
}
```

However, this gets messy quickly as the number of types grow and makes unit testing more difficult. What I would really like to do is the following:

```cs
public class WidgetsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet(MediaType = "my-awesome-product.type", MediaTypeValue = "widgetsummary")]
    public WidgetSummary GetWidgetSummary(int id)
    {
        return new WidgetSummary();
    }

    [HttpGet(MediaType = "my-awesome-product.type", MediaTypeValue = "fullwidgetforediting")]
    public FullWidgetForEditing GetFullWidgetForEditing(int id)
    {
        return new FullWidgetForEditing();
    }

    [HttpGet(MediaType = "my-awesome-product.type", MediaTypeValue = "widgetfordropdownlist")]
    public WidgetForDropDownList GetWidgetForDropDownList(int id)
    {
        return new WidgetForDropDownList();
    }
}
```

And have Web API route to the specific action method based on the media type. I investigated overriding the `ApiControllerActionSelector`, however, I started pulling in large quantities of the existing code for this attribute because I really want the default action selection, but in the case of ambiguous actions, I want to filter the list of actions based on the media type. I really want it to be non-intrusive so that I can mix convention routing, standard attribute routing (which is in Web API v2) and this hypothetical attribute routing in the same controller if need be.

Question time: is it currently possible to implement such a routing strategy with Web API as it stands? Would I have to completely reimplement the `ApiControllerActionSelector` to achieve this (and then make sure my reimplementation stays up to date)?

Comment: flipchart,

I am also looking for exactly what you described - one URL should represent 1 object (not its format, or return type).

Did you ever find a solution? I am confused as to why overriding the default selector was taking so much code, shouldn't you just handle your accept headers and if you don't get a match, pass the request down to the base class? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

So here is the question you need to ponder.  Are those really three representations, or are the three distinct resources? If you decided to cache those representations, would the URI be sufficient to identify the cached representation, or would you also need to vary on the accept header?

If you accept that they are different enough to be resources then they should be identified by different URLs.  If you decide to use hyperlinks in your responses, would you not want the ability to point to a 'widgetsummary' independently from a 'widgeteditform'?

Usually multiple representations are needed when you want to support different client devices that are only capable of supporting a certain media types.  e.g. Device A gets Rep1 and device B gets Rep2.  It's rare that you want Device A to access both Device A and Rep1 and Rep2.

Just my thoughts...

Comment: On the question itself, yes, you are right. In general flipchart points to an interesting topic nevertheless which is API versioning and routing with MediaTypes Or X-MediaTypes...